# Passing objects as parameter to method JAVA

Tags: java, oop, object

**I was given the main coding to do the sub class .**
but I was stuck in these coding as shown at the below :

```
z.setName(z.obj1);
z.setID(z.obj2);
```

**********  It should be the way to insert input. **************

========== The subClass I shown at the below was written by myself ==========

The main coding given as below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StudReg z = new StudReg();

    z.setName(z.obj1);
    z.setID(z.obj2);  

    System.out.println(z.getName());
    System.out.println(z.getID());
    System.out.println(z.getJava());
    System.out.println(z.getDatabase());

    StuComputing obj3,obj4;
    obj4 = new StuComputing();
    obj4.setStudReg(z);
    System.out.println(obj4.GPA().getGPA());
}
```

The subClass (StudReg) I've done as below :

```
public class StudReg {

//Data Member 
String Name;
String ID;
double Java,Database;

//Constructor
public StudReg(){};
public StudReg(String a,String b){
    Name = a;
    ID = b;
};



//Name
public void setName(String n){
    Name = n;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

//Id
public void setID (String i){
    ID = i;
}
public String getID (){
    return ID;
}

//Java
public void setJava (double j){
    Java = j;
}
public double getJava (){
    return Java;
}

//Database
public void setDatabase (double d){
    Database = d;
}
public double getDatabase (){
    return Database;
}



//FUNCTION
public StudReg (StudReg gg){
    double aa,bb;

    //refer to data from MAIN
    aa = this.getJava();
    bb = this.getDatabase();
}
```

Another SubClass - StuComputing:

```
public class StuComputing {

//DATA MEMBER
public StudReg ss;
double GPA;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public StuComputing (){};
public StuComputing (double a1){       
    GPA = a1;              
};



//StudReg
public void setStudReg (StudReg st){
    ss = st;
}
public StudReg getStudReg(){
    return ss;
}


//GPA
public void setGPA(double g){
    GPA = g;
}
public double getGPA(){
    return GPA;
}
```

Beside answer my problem, can you all show a simple example ?
So, I can understand it easily ><

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is most likely, because you didn´t really describe it, that your class `StudReg` neither does have a variable called `obj1` nor does it have a variable `obj2`

Comment: I was requested to do the subclass coding to support main class coding. But I can't made it. I tried the coding like public StudReg obj1 (){
       
        StudReg st = new StudReg();
        st.setName("xxxx");
        st.setID("Dg52");        
              
        return st;   

    }

but I can't make it .

Comment: does this mainclass make sense? why having a public field in StudReg just to invoke the setters on the same object to set the same value in another field of the same object... I'm confused... are obj1 and obj2 default values? shouldn't they be static then?

Comment: yap, main class works. I've tried to put public StudReg obj1 (){
       
        StudReg st = new StudReg();
        st.setName("Chai");
        st.setID("D2014");        
              
        return st;   

    }
but another error occurred. I should not do any changes in main coding. So, what should I make changes in the StudReg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have still no idea what you really want to do... try this

```
class StudReg {

String obj1 ;
String obj2 ;
double java ;
double database ;
String name ;
String id ;

public double getJava() {
    return java;
}

public double getDatabase() {
    return database;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getObj1() {
    return obj1;
}

public void setObj1(String obj1) {
    this.obj1 = obj1;
}

public String getObj2() {
    return obj2;
}

public void setObj2(String obj2) {
    this.obj2 = obj2;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

```
class StuComputing {

StudReg studReg;
GPA gpa;

public StuComputing() {
    gpa = new GPA();
}


public StudReg getStudReg() {
    return studReg;
}

public void setStudReg(StudReg sr) {
    this.studReg = sr;
}

public GPA GPA() {
 return gpa;  
}
```

}

```
public class GPA {
double gpa;

public GPA() {
}


public double getGPA(){
    return gpa;
}
```

}

Comment: Object obj1;
Object obj2;
Object java;
Object database;
Object name;
Object id;

these are considered as data member ?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but the output doesn't work. This is because there is a calculation in StuComputing. I have to get 'Java' and 'Database' mark for calculation GPA which is located at StuComputing.

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten something. there is no "obj1" or "obj2" attribute in your class StudReg.

So how can we understand your problem? I think you need to ask your question again in other wording.

Comment: because my lecture just gave me the main coding. I was requested to build up the sub class - StudReg.

Comment: if I want to add the obj1 in my subclass, would it like this :
public StudReg obj1 (){ String n; Name=n;}????

Comment: Hi, if you write "z.obj1", like you do, you refer to an attribute of z (which is instance of StudyReg), what you want is to have instance called "obj1". 

Read carefully: 

You should create obj1: obj1 = new StudyReg() 
Assign a value to its name property: obj1.setName("Chai Jin Ying") , 
Then assign the name-property of obj1 to z: z.setName(obj1.getName()) 

When you have tried this, read a book about programming for starters, and take good care. Success.

Comment: I've tried to put public StudReg obj1 (){ StudReg st = new StudReg(); st.setName("Chai"); st.setID("D2014"); return st; } but another error occurred. I should not do any changes in main coding. So, what should I make changes in the StudReg ?

Comment: Sorry, these questions are very basic. Try a good book, and don't stick to examples, but work to understanding.

http://www.amazon.com/Java-For-Dummies-Barry-Burd/dp/1118407806